# Is there any recent review of the book "Scripts, Plans, Goals, and Understanding: An Inquiry Into Human Knowledge Structures"?

Tags: cognitive-modeling, artificial-intelligence

My advisor asked me to read [this book](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1979-07723-000). However, I wonder if there is some recent review of the book that integrates AI and cognitive findings in recent years. Just want to know if there's any view in the book that is outdated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really how scientific publishing works; people don't typically "review" old books.

They do cite them, though. You can search for a book or paper on Google Scholar and click the "[cited by](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=9638805451784711080&as_sdt=5,50&sciodt=0,50&hl=en)" link to see all the work that has cited that book. From there, you can see how different sources are using it: are there specific theories or conclusions that are referenced? Are they mostly criticizing it as outdated? Do they cite other, newer work alongside it that you might also read?

You can also search *within* the cited work; [adding "review" to your search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=5%2C50&sciodt=0%2C50&cites=9638805451784711080&scipsc=1&q=review&btnG=) might find you recent reviews that have cited this book among others; you shouldn't expect any of them to cover that specific source in depth, but they might cover a similar topic (or they could be in an adjacent area).

All of this can be quite the undertaking, though that's what research is, so it would be helpful to start with some idea of what you're looking for. That might come from paging through the original book or from starting with considering why your advisor recommended this book.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really provides me with a lot of resources, checking them right now!